# How to change the color of a clicked mat-list-item from a list of numbers

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm not able to change the `background-color` of the `mat-list-item` when it's clicked

I'm able to change the color of mat-list-item if I hover over it, but not when clicked. The snapshot of my UI when I hover on `mat-list-item` is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVh2k.jpg

This is all I've already coded: https://pastebin.com/raw/EMzH5nsq

Expect the change from the `background-color` of the `mat-list-item` on click

Comment: Hello @sai. Please include a minimal example of your code in your question (see here for formatting : https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: What you were using `mat-nav-list` or `mat-list`?